# List of all pub-sub items for a particular user in Smack API?

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am creating the Node using the PUBSUB protocol using the link
http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/pubsub.html

Could anyone help me to get the list of items subscribed,created for a particular user? Here's my code:

```
PubSubManager manager = PubSubManager.getInstance(connection);
LeafNode leaf = mgr.createNode("testNode");
ConfigureForm form = new ConfigureForm(FormType.submit);
form.setAccessModel(AccessModel.open);
form.setDeliverPayloads(false);
form.setNotifyRetract(true);
form.setPersistentItems(true);
form.setPublishModel(PublishModel.open);
leaf.sendConfigurationForm(form);
```

I am willing to do something like this

```
manager.getAllListofSubscriedItems(){
// TO DO Implementation here, **Need some idea here**
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but people are willing to help you if you at least try to solve the problem at your own. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then, update and *improve your question*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PubSubManager` to discover nodes tree.
Use

- `discoverNodes`
- `getAffiliations()`

http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/

Comment: Hi Antoniossss, I am getting the following error.
`W/AbstractXMPPConnection: Connection XMPPTCPConnection[user0@myserver.local/5pqgr3nw88] (0) closed with error
                                                                                          org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException: Invalid affililation`